# Given a dataset with Normal values and outliers, is there any standard way to find a normalised value of epsilon for implementing DBSCAN.

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, outliers, dbscan

I am working on my personal implementation of DBSCAN on some data, but I have problems when I have to find epsilon dynamically for every kind of data set I have to use, because average value of epsilon before implementing DBSCAN considers the outliers as well, and hence the resultant epsilon has the effect of the outlier value as well, which is problematic for me. Is there any way to counter this?

This is the part of the code which calculates the epsilon for the specific dataset:

```
xmax = np.max(X,axis = 0)
xmin = np.min(X,axis = 0)
min_max = xmax-xmin
k = 10
eps = (min_max[0]*min_max[1]*k/(len(X)*math.pi))**0.5
```

I have used some functions like max, min from the numpy module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If finding the appropriate value of epsilon is a major problem, the *real* problem may be long before that: you may be using the wrong distance measure all the way, or you may have a **preprocessing problem**.

Your code looks a lot like a naive preprocessing approach - and that is how good it will work.

Also read the DBSCAN paper. The authors propose a way of choosing epsilon in section 4.2, and you may be able to automate this...

Comment: My data set has a peculiarity, that the distribution of the points in 2-d space is not in the form of blobs, but it is somewhat like discontinuous curves, which makes it difficult to implement the epsilon approximation method as discussed in the section 4.2 of the original DBSCAN paper

Comment: Maybe just go for OPTICS where you don't need to set epsilon at all?

Comment: I am working on optics, but given the fact the no Python implementation is there, I need time for that. Meanwhile, I need to produce good results with DBscan for 'Research' purposes

Comment: ELKI has a fully working implementation of OPTICS. You could try if the results work for you before implementing it yourself.

Comment: Also note that the availability of an implementation doesn't mean it is a good implementation. Compare e.g. kmeans from scipy to kmeans from sklearn. A massive difference, I couldn't believe it when I first saw it. (And maybe it will be gone in the next version)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments, you have the following alternatives:
 1. OPTICS
 2. BIRCH
 3. Mean Shift Algorithm
 4. Local Outlier Factor
 5. The most difficult one, but the best in your case (as far as I can get it) : Use Neural Networks

Comment: Too many algorithms..!! Are you into data mining or something?